# Question of partial differential with change of variables.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Show that the equation

$k\frac{\partial^2{\phi}}{\partial{x^2}}=\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t}}$, $(k>0)$

is transformed by the introduction of the new independent variables

$\xi=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}}, \zeta=t$

into

$k\frac{\partial^2{\varphi}}{\partial{\xi^2}}+2\xi\frac{\partial{\varphi}}{\partial{xi}}=4\zeta\frac{\partial{\varphi}}{\partial{\zeta}}$

Where $\varphi(\xi,\zeta)=\phi(x,t)$

---

Using chain Rule,

$\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{\xi}}.\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial x}$

From above,

$x=\xi2\sqrt{t}$

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial{\xi}}=\frac{4t+\xi}{2\sqrt{2}} \rightarrow \frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial x}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{4t+\xi}$

I just substitute in

$\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{\xi}}.\frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial x}$

$\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{\xi}} [\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{4t+\xi}]$

Similarly, I can calculate for $\frac{\partial^2{\phi}}{\partial x^2}$, but I do not find where this can lead to the answer.

Comment: It's not true that $\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} = \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} \right)^{-1}$. Look up the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz, I am seeing this partial a bit difficult to solve, could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your change of variable and the chain rule on $\phi(x,t) = \psi(\xi(x,t), \zeta(t))$, we get

\begin{align}
\phi_{x} &= \psi_{\xi} \cdot \xi_{x} \\
&= \psi_{\xi} \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}} \\
\implies \phi_{xx} &= \psi_{\xi \xi} \cdot \frac{1}{4t} \\
\phi_{t} &= \psi_{\xi} \cdot \xi_{t} + \psi_{\zeta} \cdot \zeta_{t} \\
&= \psi_{\xi} \cdot \frac{-x}{4 t^{3/2}} + \psi_{\zeta} \cdot 1
\end{align}

and so our original PDE becomes

\begin{align}
\phi_{t} &= k \phi_{xx} \\
\implies \psi_{\xi} \cdot \frac{-x}{4 t^{3/2}} + \psi_{\zeta} \cdot 1 &= k \psi_{\xi \xi} \cdot \frac{1}{4t} \\
\implies 4t \psi_{\zeta} - \psi_{\xi} \cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}} &= k \psi_{\xi \xi} \\
\implies 4 \zeta \psi_{\zeta} - 2\xi \psi_{\xi} &= k\psi_{\xi \xi} \\
\implies 4 \zeta \psi_{\zeta} &= 2\xi \psi_{\xi} + k\psi_{\xi \xi}
\end{align}